# Using Ubuntu host to create/manage Retropie

Tags: ubuntu

Every guide on how to set up a raspberry pi assumes the user is using a Windows computer, but Im running Ubuntu on my computer. Any guides on how to set up/manage with a linux host computer? Thanks

Comment: FYI, there's a dedicated [raspberrypi.se] site.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to setup raspberry pi with raspbian(or any of the OS(es) listed here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) use this link:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md

It has instructions for Windows, Linux(linux includes ubuntu), and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missed the linux instructions because they're the simplest, so if you are scrolling down a page filled with Windows and OSX screenshots that short paragraph could be hard to spot.

You run:

```
 dd if=whatever.img of=/dev/sdx
```

Where `sdx` is the SD card device (not `sdx3`, which would be a partition on `sdx`), and `whatever.img` is the name of the image you want to install.  Done.  The end.

It might take a few minutes to complete.  You can include `status=progress` to get a clue about have far it's gotten after how long.

You do not need to preformat the card, etc., regardless of how it was or was not previously used.  Just that one command.